# Magento 2 How to hide price from front end with custom module?

Tags: magento2, checkout, module, orders, price

I have created one module and it has system configuration on the admin side, where the admin has the functionality to enable/disable the module. As per system configuration, I need to hide the price from every place on the front end.

> i.e. "catalog, category, wishlist, a related product, upsell products,
>   cart, checkout, orders, email, account dashboard, etc.."

from everywhere I need to hide the price if the module is enabled.

Is there any global file for the price which can be overridden and add the code for hiding price?

I found one file, But if we override `\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox` and change in `wrapResult()` function, it works but it will affect only product page and home page not for wishlist and other places.

how can I achieve this functionality? Is anyone have any idea about it?

Please share an idea to hide price from cart/checkout/order/etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to succeed in hiding price from whole frontend area with a custom module.

I have di.xml as below:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Sales\Order" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeList" />
<preference for="Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Directory\PriceCurrency" />
```

I override below files and update functions as needed, Here I list out all the files and functions:

```
Hide price from Customer account section, Order view, etc.
- Vendor\Module\Model\Sales\Order.php

==>> function formatPrice($price, $addBrackets = false)
```

```
Hide price from the product, category, new products, related, upsell, cross-sell, etc.
- Vendor\Module\Model\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox.php

==>> function wrapResult($html)
```

```
Hide price filter from left / right navigation
- Vendor\Module\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeList.php
==>> 
class FilterableAttributeList extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList
{
    protected $collectionFactory;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $helperData;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helperData
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;        
        parent::__construct($collectionFactory, $storeManager);
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
    }

    protected function _prepareAttributeCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection->addIsFilterableFilter();
        $collection->removePriceFilter();
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

```
Hide price cart items
- Vendor\Module\Model\Directory\PriceCurrency.php

==>>  function format(
        $amount,
        $includeContainer = true,
        $precision = self::DEFAULT_PRECISION,
        $scope = null,
        $currency = null
    )
```

```
 Hide price from product options, cart total, checkcout totals
- Vendor\Module\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js

==>> var config = {
        'config': {
            'mixins': {
                'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils': {
                    'Vendor_Module/js/price-utils-mixin': true
                }
            }
        }
    };

- Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\js\price-utils-mixin.js
==>> 

/**
 * @api
 */
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore'
], function ($, _) {
    'use strict';

    var globalPriceFormat = {
        requiredPrecision: 2,
        integerRequired: 1,
        decimalSymbol: ',',
        groupSymbol: ',',
        groupLength: ','
    };

    return function (target) {

        target.formatPrice = function formatPrice(amount, format, isShowSign) {
            var s = '', precision, integerRequired, decimalSymbol, groupSymbol, groupLength, pattern, i, pad, j, re, r, am;

            format = _.extend(globalPriceFormat, format);

            // copied from price-option.js | Could be refactored with varien/js.js

            precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision;
            integerRequired = isNaN(format.integerRequired = Math.abs(format.integerRequired)) ? 1 : format.integerRequired;
            decimalSymbol = format.decimalSymbol === undefined ? ',' : format.decimalSymbol;
            groupSymbol = format.groupSymbol === undefined ? '.' : format.groupSymbol;
            groupLength = format.groupLength === undefined ? 3 : format.groupLength;
            pattern = format.pattern || '%s';

            if (isShowSign === undefined || isShowSign === true) {
                s = amount  groupLength ? i.length % groupLength : 0;
            re = new RegExp('(\\d{' + groupLength + '})(?=\\d)', 'g');

            // replace(/-/, 0) is only for fixing Safari bug which appears
            // when Math.abs(0).toFixed() executed on '0' number.
            // Result is '0.-0' :(

            am = Number(Math.round(Math.abs(amount - i) + 'e+' + precision) + ('e-' + precision));
            r = (j ? i.substr(0, j) + groupSymbol : '') +
                i.substr(j).replace(re, '$1' + groupSymbol) +
                (precision ? decimalSymbol + am.toFixed(precision).replace(/-/, 0).slice(2) : '');      

                //return pattern.replace('%s', r).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
                return '';
        };

        return target;
    };    

    /**
     * Repeats {string} {times} times
     * @param  {String} string
     * @param  {Number} times
     * @return {String}
     */
    function stringPad(string, times) {
        return (new Array(times + 1)).join(string);
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox as BasePriceBox;
use Magento\Msrp\Pricing\Price\MsrpPrice;


class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{ 
    protected function wrapResult($html)
    {
        return '';
    }

}
```

Comment: i already used above code but it only hide price from category, product view. not other  pages. mentioned in question.

Comment: Partially accepted. :)